# What is the smallest type that can be used for a render texture in a compute shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, directx, compute-shader

I'm using unity's compute shader to write into a render texture that will be used later. The values I want to enter into my render texture are 0 and 1, therefore to avoid using a lot of useless memory, I'm looking for the smaller type that can be used for a render texture in a compute shader.

I saw that the render texture format at his creation on CPU can be set to `RenderTextureFormat.R8`, I try to used it but I don't know which type to use when declaring the render texture in compute shader (it doesn't work with `_int8`). Moreover, I saw that I can use the type `bool` when I declare the render texture in compute shader, but then I don't know which render texture format to use...

Comment: [unorm float](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ComputeShader.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Shingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6196568/shingo) said, the smaller type is a 8 bit integer which is defined in render texture creation by `RenderTextureFormat.R8` and then in render texture declaration in compute shader by `unorm float`.
There is a [table](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ComputeShader.html) in Unity Manual that summarize the different `RenderTextureFormat` and there equivalent in `HLSL` for compute shader.